# Ubuntu does not run fullscreen in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, fullscreen

As a host OS I am running Windows 7 Enterprise. I've installed VM (VirtualBox) and I have there installed Guest OS Ubuntu 14.01 LTS. I've install GuestAdditions. After that the guest OS ran nicely fullscreen for several weeks. However, suddenly this time I've started VM and the guest OS it blits for like a second to fullscreen and then it shrinks to maybe 50% in each axis. I've tried reinstalling GuestAdditions, rebooting, restarting VM. Nothing works.

Comment: You never made a mention of which virtualization program you're using.

Comment: @AndroidDev My bad, sorry! For some reason I typed VM instead of VB.

Answer (score 0):

For my system (Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS) after I've booted the VM and it's shrunk on me I went to View - Auto-resize Guest Display.

Then select full-screen mode. I've found after retelling VB to resize, it full-screens properly